# Will the real "Biblical basis for sola scriptura" question please stand up?

Tags: discussion

[What is the Biblical Basis for Sola Scriptura?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-sola-scriptura) was closed as a duplicate of [What is the basis of my fractured understanding of  "Sola Scriptura"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-the-basis-of-my-fractured-understanding-of-sola-scriptura) even though that one [isn't actually about sola scriptura](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1116/9289). Meanwhile, that's what this hard-to-find and sort of unclear question seems to be asking: [Why is the Bible a foundation of theological evidence?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3307/9289)

My proposal: we reopen the first question and then close the last as a duplicate of the first.

Or better yet, since the first question is poorly asked, long-closed, and by an inactive user, it could stay closed and a *new* question could be asked.

Comment: I think a new question would be best because many things get called sola scriptura which are really distinct doctrines.

Comment: @curiousdannii I just had another thought. What if I edited the last question to ask for the Biblical basis for sola scriptura? I _think_ that's what it's asking anyway.

Comment: [This question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3307/6071) I don't think that would be helpful, it looks to me like it wants a non-circular explanation for the inspiration of scripture. But mixed up with ranking reason and experience higher than scripture too.

Comment: @curiousdannii Maybe it should just be closed as unclear?

Comment: Yeah, it's asking quite a few different things.

Answer (score 2):

A little backgrounder My questions was question #2 on the site (#1 was closed, but it was a good one). It was asked in the 1 hour window when it was just me and the robots (I hit f5 a lot).  It was originally titled "What is the basis for Sola Scriptura", but then when all the Protestants jumped on it telling me I had totally misunderstood and misrepresented Sola Scriptura, it became apparent that I had to change the title or have yet another complete loser question.

I'm not sure why they left it open to be honest, "my fractured understanding" seems a little um... localized.  But whatever, I think it got lots of good responses and you can probably learn more from that question than you can raising a new one.

Comment: "you can probably learn more from that question than you can raising a new one." This.

Comment: Examining the edit history and comments is instructive as to what can go wrong with an SE question when you confuse terms (ie provide your own private definitions of them) and as a result have a mismatch between the title of a question and its body (as far as how the vast majority of other people will interpret them), but overall the post is unnecessarily obfuscatory with regards to an appropriately focused question on "What is the basis of Sola Scriptura?" - despite the quality and range of answers, it makes a lot of sense to champion an entirely different question.